# WPF Send combox's selected value to another window's identical combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a window at startup where you select an Interface and Port from 2 comboboxs. When you click Done, it takes you to the main window, where you can see 2 more comboxes that are identical. These have the selected values as what you just picked in the popup window. Can I do this in the code behind?

Here's my popup window, `winResetInterface.xaml`:

```
Window x:Class="simpliphy.winResetInterface"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="winResetInterface" Height="280" Width="259">
<Grid Margin="0,-1,2,1">
    <ComboBox Name="cmbInterface" ItemsSource="{Binding Interface}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="94,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnFinishSetup" Click="btnFinishSetup_Click" Content="Done" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,173,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
   <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPort"  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Port, ElementName=cmbInterface}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="94,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91"/>
</Grid>
```

And in my code behind:

```
     namespace project
    {

        public partial class winResetInterface : Window
        {
            public ObservableCollection<Model.Device_Class> Interface { get; set; }

                public winResetInterface()
                {
                   InitializeComponent();
                   DataContext = this;
                   Interface = new ObservableCollection<Model.Device_Class>();
                   Interface.Add(new Device_Class() { Name = "XGBE", Port = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "0" } });
                   Interface.Add(new Device_Class() { Name = "SATA0", Port = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "0", "1", "2", "3" } });
                 }
          }

        private void btnFinishSetup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
            App.Current.MainWindow = main;
            this.Close();
            main.Show();

            //Set the selected options on the device stats sidebar
            ///THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK!
            main.cmbInterface_main.SelectedItem = cmbInterface.SelectedItem;


        }
    }
```

In my MainWindow, I have a combobox that is filled the same way as box1, cmbInterface. Can I not just set the 2 selecteditems equal to each other?

Comment: Right way to do this is to transport a model between the two windows using MVVM. You are trying to do a winforms in Wpf. It can be done but will be a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
main.cmbInterface_main.SelectedIndex = cmbInterface_main.FindStringExact(cmbInterface.Text, 0);
```

although loopedcode's comment is a better answer.